# Opening Image from Website

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, python-requests

I was trying to make a simple program to pull an image from the website xkcd.com, and I seem to be running into a problem where it returns list object has no attribute show. Anyone know how to fix this?

```
import requests
from lxml import html

r = requests.get("http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/self_driving_issues.png")
tree = html.fromstring(r.content)
final = tree.xpath("""//*[@id="comic"]/img""")
final.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to requests.get is retrieving the actual image, the byte code for the png. There is no html to parse or search for with xpath.

Note here, the content is bytes:

```
r = requests.get("http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/self_driving_issues.png")
print(r.content)

b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x02\xe4\x00\x00\x01#\x08\x03\x00\x00\x00M\x7f\xe4\xc6\x00\x00\x00\x04gAMA\x00\x00\xb1\x8f
```

Here you see that you can save the results directly to disk.

```
import requests

r = requests.get("http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/self_driving_issues.png")
with open("myimage.png", "wb") as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

[Edit] And to Show the image (you will need to install [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html).)

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
import io

r = requests.get("http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/self_driving_issues.png")

img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(r.content))
img.show()
```

Comment: how would you do it without saving to disk?

Comment: @leo_someone ; If this answers your question - please mark it as such. If not, please follow up.